# Multiple sed commands in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a a file usernames and passwords in JSON format that I want to convert to process.

I have used `sed` in different commands to process it but what I would like to know is how to lump all three commands into one for the future.

Original format

```
    { "user.name1" : "hashed_password",
"user.name2" : "hashed_password" }
```

Desired output

```
user.name:hashed_password
```

These are the commands I ran, however I have been unable to chain them together using either piping or simply concatenating them where I get an error, `sed:  -e expression #1, char 8: unknown option to 's'`.

Offending command...

```
sed -i 's/\"//g/s/\,/\n/g/\s//g' input_file 
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unknown option to `s'
```

How could the below commands be concatenated into one?

Commands
Remove double quotes

`sed -i 's/\"//g' input_file`

Replace comma with new line

`sed -i 's/\,/\n/g' input_file`

Remove whitespace

`sed -i 's/\s//g input_file`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To put multiple `sed` commands in a single "*script*", you can use multiple `-e` flags (which is portable):

```
sed -i -e 's/\"//g' -e 's/\,/\n/g' -e 's/\s//g' input_file
```

Or the semicolon delimiter (which is not available on all implementations):

```
sed -i 's/\"//g;s/\,/\n/g;s/\s//g' input_file
```

You'll need to add handling for the braces too - `{}`...

---

Having said this, to parse and handle JSON properly, you shouldn't really use `sed`... perhaps try [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)!

```
jq -r 'keys[] as $k | "\($k):\(.[$k])"' input_file
```

Output:

```
user.name1:hashed_password
user.name2:hashed_password
```

- `keys[] as $k` will iterate through each key storing its value in `$k`

  - i.e: `user.name1`, `user.name2`
- `"\($k):\(.[$k])"` will form a string, substituting in `$k` and `.[$k]`
- Using `-r` removes the quotes from output strings (*raw* mode)

---

Using `sed` to process JSON is going to open you up to all sorts of issues... for example, how would you deal with the following (completely valid JSON) input?

```
{
    "user.name1" :
        "hashed_password",
    "user.name2" :
        "hashed_password"
}
```

Comment: If you want your first sed command to be even more portable, you should do `sed -i '' -e …` to get it right on BSD. Otherwise you'll end up having a saved backup file named `input_file-e`

Answer (score 3):

When you're dealing with standardised input like JSON, it's generally better to use a proper parser rather than regex. For example, you'll correctly convert any escape sequences (though that may not be possible with your particular input data!).

Unfortunately, there's no great tools for dealing with JSON within coreutils. [Attie's provided](https://superuser.com/a/1380680/117590) `jq` as a decent option if you are free to install packages.

If you're unable to install additional packages, it's not particularly difficult in Python. Take this script for example:

```
import json,sys
for (k, v) in json.load(sys.stdin):
    print(k + ":" + v)
```

Which can be compressed into one line:

```
cat inputdata | python -c 'import json,sys;print("\n".join((k + ":" + v) for (k, v) in json.load(sys.stdin).items()))'
```

Answer (score 0):

For the simple character deletion you're doing in these `sed` commands I would instead recommend you use `tr`, whose sole purpose is to delete, squeeze, or replace individual characters, including newlines (`sed` is based on regex's, which normally rely on newlines as buffer separators, so using sed to modify newlines is tricky). I think this `tr` command does everything you're looking for:

```
cat json_filename | tr -d "{}\" \012\011\015" | tr "," "\012"
```

The first `tr` command deletes all curly braces, double-quotes, spaces, carriage returns (octal 012, ascii 10), tabs (octal 011, ascii 9, and linefeed (octal 015, ascii 13) characters. The second `tr` command replaces all commas with carriage returns. As long as your JSON file's variable names and values don't contain commas, these commands would allow you to avoid needing a dedicated JSON parser.

That said, if you have a set of `sed` commands that each work independently, combining them may be most easily accomplished using the "-f" `sed` option to read the separate commands  from a file. You just put the s/.../.../g strings into a file, each string on its own line, then specify that filename after the "-f" option. For example, if the three `sed` commands you listed are satisfactory, you could put them into a file named "json.convert.sed" that simply contained this:

```
s/\"//g 
s/\,/\n/g
s/\s//g
```

Then you would invoke `sed` with this command file using:

```
sed -f json.convert.sed
```

That said, these `sed` commands don't work for me to accomplish what you want, and I'm not sure you can ever get `sed` to modify newline characters. This is because `sed` is based on the old "ed" line editor, designed to edit single lines at a time (a "script"-able version of it), so each line of input is "parsed" using newlines as the delimiters, then the line (without the newline) is passed to the editing engine, the editing commands are applied, then the edited line is output with a newline. Then the loop repeats. I've only ever been able to use `sed` to modify newline by first changing the newlines to some distinct character (that doesn't otherwise appear in the input) using `tr`. There's no point to using `tr` this way if all you want to do is delete newlines, since `tr` will do that for you. But if, for instance, you wanted to convert newlines to semicolons with a trailing space, one way to do that would be:

```
cat input_file | tr "\012" "%" | sed "s/%/; /g"
```

(newlines are converted to % by `tr`, then `sed` converts all % characters to "; " character pairs.)

Answer (score 0):

Sed can handle multi-line editing, but I agree with Attie and Bob, parse json with sed regex can become a nightmare.

```
sed -nr '/\{/ b Load ; d
: Load
/\}/ b Edit ; N ; b Load
: Edit ; s/[^"]+"([^"]+)"[^"]+"([^"]+)"(.*)/\1:\2\n\3/ ; t Print ; d
: Print ; P ; s/[^\n]+\n// ; t Edit' <<'eof'
{
    "user.name1" :
        "hashed_password1",
    "user.name2" :
        "hashed_password2"
}
    { "user.name3" : "hashed_password3",
"user.name4" : "hashed_password4" }

{ "user.name5":"hashed_password5"}
eof

user.name1:hashed_password1
user.name2:hashed_password2
user.name3:hashed_password3
user.name4:hashed_password4
user.name5:hashed_password5
```

Answer (score -1):

You could combine it like this:

`sed -i 's/\"//g;s/\,/\n/g;s/\s//g' input_file`

You forgot to add the removal of `{}`. So you probably want:

`sed -i 's/\"//g;s/\,/\n/g;s/\s//g;s/{//g;s/}//g' input_file`